# ContentProvider BulkInsert and ApplyBatch

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

In my application I am currently writing over 700 items to the database using a content provider. For some reason when I try to do all of the items at once using:

```
 mContentResolver.bulkInsert(mContentUri, insertVals));
```

where insertVals is a ContentValues[] with 700 items it. Each Time i do this I get 0 rows returned. But when I break up the call to bulkInsert so that each insert only has 100 items, it works perfectly. This new way seems inefficient. Does anyone have any insight into why this may be happening? I have been unable to find documentation of a max number of items you can insert using bulkInsert.

**NOTE** I have tried to use ApplyBatch as well, and I have gotten the exact same results. When I do it for all 700 items it doesn't work. When I do it for 100 items at a time it works like a charm.

Thanks for all the Help!

Comment: I don't think there is any limit for `ContentResolver.bulkInsert`. Because I remember I have tried this in one of my application for inserting around 500-600 rows...
Just confirm your data is not violating any Database constraint.

Comment: @VishalVyas Can you show us an example of this, especially how you validate each row so that the whole insert doesn't fail.